# Is Proj4JS-definition for EPSG:3021 (RT90) wrong on https://epsg.io/3021?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

I'm writing a webapplication which handles coordinate transformations to and from WGS84.

The defs for `EPSG:3021` (RT90, Sweden) from https://epsg.io/3021, looks like this:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:3021","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.8082777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=414.1,41.3,603.1,0.855,-2.141,7.023,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs");
```

The interesting part is the `+towgs84`-parameter:

```
+towgs84=414.1,41.3,603.1,0.855,-2.141,7.023,0
```

When using this definition, the transformed coordinates is about 100m off.

Instead I found this in forum-posts:

```
+towgs84=414.1,41.3,603.1,-0.855,2.141,-7.023,0
```

which seems to give good results. Note the diffrence between `0.855,-2.141,7.023` and `-0.855,2.141,-7.023`.

I want to have an auto import of defs from epsg.io, so I want to understand why the defs for https://epsg.io/3021 doesn't work, or is it fact an error in the records?

Comment: @BERA, maybe you can help in Sweden @_@

Comment: I encourage using the https://epsg.org/crs_3021/RT90-2-5-gon-V.html. QGIS gives me `+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.8082777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=414.1,41.3,603.1,-0.855,2.141,-7.023,0 +units=m +no_defs`

Comment: This shows also reverted signs for the last three parameters `projinfo epsg:3021 PROJ.4 string:
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.8082777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=414.1,41.3,603.1,-0.855,2.141,-7.023,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs` Probably there has been an error when data has been imported into the unofficial (but easy to use) epsg.io site.

Comment: Thanks! I posted an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/maptiler/epsg.io/issues/190).

Comment: Is there a way to get the PROJ-defs directly from epsg.org. Or do I need to use the API?